# How to load react/react-dom in a single html page?

Tags: reactjs

React and/or react-dom are not loading properly.  But why not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src='babel.min.js'type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='react.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='react-dom.js' type='text/javascript'></script>


    <script type="text/babel">

    class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>Hello world</div>
            );
        }
    }   

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first complaint is
react.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react.js:14

react.js and react-dom.js are both version 16.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ultimate goal was to take a developed react app and deploy it to an Apache or Nginx server. Instead of using the CDN, what I should have done, was to

1. Edit the package.json file to reflect the applications final destination
2. Run "npm run build"
3. Copied the contents of the build directory to my final target location

See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build
and
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripts hosted from a cdn like these...

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Just copy paste that and replace what you have... or if you want to host it on your own server, you can view source and copy paste them on a file. Also, please make sure that they're on the correct order.

You can also find a working example on this react guide - https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#creating-a-new-application

Hope this helps! Thank :)

### UPDATE:

Other options you can do to setup React locally will be...

1.) Setup your local dev environment and workflow by using bundlers like Browserify or Webpack. For that you have to have knowledge with npm and webpack. Here's a good setup tutorial if you want to do it all by yourself - https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-i

2.) Use create-react-app, which is a quick starter kit from Facebook. Here's the link to their repo - https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: You are right.  Using your script tags resolves the problem, but can we continue the discussion a little longer.  I copied the urls and converted them into anchor tags and then did a save link as on each one.  And the result still fails.  Its as if loading them from the CDN is somehow different from loading them locally.  But how can that be?

Comment: And I kept the order as you suggested:  react, then react-dom, and then babel.

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but honestly I wouldn't really recommend you to plainly copy the scripts on your own files even if that would work. IMHO, I think the best way is to setup your local dev environment and workflow by using bundlers like Browserify or Webpack. For that you have to have knowledge with npm and webpack. Here's a good setup tutorial if you want to do it all by yourself - 

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-i

Comment: You can also use create-react-app which is an official starter kit from Facebook.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

and Lastly (the easiest one) is to again, use minified and CDN-hosted scripts

Comment: btw, if you don't mind, I've also updated the answer so it can easily be seen by others. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for making the answer more visible to others.  SO rocks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160652/discussion-between-p-h-and-bawun).